# No such image: testcontainers/byvren8fgzpzaxgy:latest

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect, docker-registry, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

When I tried to write the integration test for the Kafka container I get this error after trying to build the project. I have no idea what is going wrong.

```
22:46:01.464 [Thread-4] WARN  o.t.utility.ResourceReaper - Unable to delete image testcontainers/byvren8fgzpzaxgy
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: Status 404: {"message":"No such image: testcontainers/byvren8fgzpzaxgy:latest"}
```

I am using the version 1.15.1 org.testcontainers maven dependency. Is there any suggestion on what is going wrong?

Comment: can you please share your test and do you have any modifications inside your `.testcontainers.properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue happens when you had a couple of integration tests running locally and each test requires a separate test container.
Having all of the tests conducted locally with the help of a single test container solves the issue.